# PostgreSQL to OracleSQL query convertion help needed

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a PostgreSQL query here that counts capitalized characters from a "word" table column:

```
sum(length(substring(word from '^[A-Z]*'))) as capitalized_sum;
```

I need to convert it to Oracle SQL query.

I tried:

```
sum(length(regexp_like('^[A-Z]*'))) from word as capitalized_sum;
```

but that gives me "SQL command not properly ended" message. Any help?

Comment: REGEXP_LIKE is used as a predicate, thus you can say `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM capitalized_sum WHERE regexp_like(WORD, '^[A-Z]*')`. Do you want to count all the capitalized characters in each word regardless of position or just count the words that are capitalized?

Comment: You need regexp_replace, not regexp_like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found what I need. Here is the OracleSQL query:

```
select sum(length(REGEXP_SUBSTR(word, '^[A-Z]*'))) as capitalized_sum from mytable;
```